# Array of structs including a function which gets called when selected in Go

Tags: go

I'm fairly new to Go, and am a little puzzled how to achieve this:

I'm using promptui to give the user a list of options to pick from. I want to assign a function to each option, when selected - the chosen item's function gets called.

The closest example for the implementation is this, which is in their docs: https://github.com/manifoldco/promptui/blob/master/_examples/custom_select/main.go

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function field to the struct and initialize:

```
type pepper struct {
    Name     string
    HeatUnit int
    Peppers  int
    fn       func() // add arguments and return values as a needed.
}

peppers := []pepper{
    {Name: "Bell Pepper", HeatUnit: 0, Peppers: 0, fn: func() { fmt.Println("Bell") }},
    ...
}
```

Call the function after the selection:

```
...

peppers[i].fn() // call function

fmt.Printf("You choose number %d: %s\n", i+1, peppers[i].Name)

...
```

BTW, it's a slice of struct values, not an array.